# how to export all branch changed files compared to local master from git

Tags: windows, git, export

I am using the following to export all the changed files from my master branch:

```
git archive --output=test_v2.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only master)
```

however it gives me the following error:

```
error: unknown option `name-only'
usage: git archive [<options>] <tree-ish> [<path>...]
   or: git archive --list
   or: git archive --remote <repo> [--exec <cmd>] [<options>] <tree-ish> [<path>...]
   or: git archive --remote <repo> [--exec <cmd>] --list

--format <fmt>        archive format
--prefix <prefix>     prepend prefix to each pathname in the archive
-o, --output <file>   write the archive to this file
--worktree-attributes
                      read .gitattributes in working directory
-v, --verbose         report archived files on stderr
-0                    store only
-1                    compress faster
-9                    compress better

-l, --list            list supported archive formats

--remote <repo>       retrieve the archive from remote repository <repo>
--exec <command>      path to the remote git-upload-archive command
```

what am I doing wrong?

it creates test_v2.zip but it is empty.

based on my research I think I should not use $ sign but I don't know what to use then.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works fine in `bash`. But you try to run it in `cmd.exe`. The `$()` syntax is Bash syntax to start a subshell, execute the enclosed command and replace the construct with the output.

Either do the same in Git Bash (anyway the better choice) or use a `cmd.exe` specific construct instead if one exists.

Comment: I am doing it in Git CMD though.

Comment: but in my Git CMD I can do cls which is a command line tool so I am kinda confused

Comment: Yes, as I said, you are doing it in `cmd.exe`, not in Bash. You just repeat what I said. `Git CMD` is not much else than `cmd.exe`. Especially you *of course* cannot use Bash specific syntax in it. That's why it is `Git CMD`, not `Git Bash`.